# How to detect if a user pressed Ctrl-Alt-Del or Alt-Tab so that I may minimize my program?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx-11, winmain, alt-tab

I'm writing a program in C++ using DirectX 11, and I would like to have it so that my program minimizes whenever a user presses Ctrl-Alt-Del or Alt-Tab.

Getting the window itself to minimize is the easy part, as all I have to do is call this function:

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

The part I'm stuck on is getting it to detect when either of those two particular keystrokes are inputted, so that I may call that function when one of those events occur.

Any assistance would be appreciated, and if you need me to clarify on something please let me know.

Comment: Why are you trying to minimize? Doesn't Windows itself display what it needs to over the top of your window?

Comment: Minimizing isn't exactly the point in my question. The reason why I would like to know how to properly handle Ctrl-Alt-Del and Alt-Tab is so that my program will behave nicely when input by the user, and that this knowledge of handling said events can be useful in the future.

Comment: That was the point of my question - Windows should do the right thing so that your program doesn't have to "behave nicely", it's automatic and there's nothing you can or should do to influence the process. I was wondering if you had some specific circumstance in mind.

Comment: Alright here is one circumstance that I need to solve. When my program is in full-screen and I hit alt-tab, it goes to windowed mode. I would much rather have it minimize.

Comment: Your best bet is to detect the resulting state rather than the keystrokes you think will get you there.  I suspect what you really want is a message when your window is no longer the active window - in that case, look for [`WM_ACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `WA_INACTIVE` message parameter.  This should be triggered for both ALT+TAB and CTRL+ALT+DELETE, along with any other unexpected interruptions such as an incoming phone call or an urgent update.

Comment: There is no automatism that changes a fullscreen DirectX application to go to windowed mode when [Alt]+[Tab]ing away from it. This is something you (or the framework you are using) has implemented. Remove the code that switches to windowed mode and move on.

Answer (score 2):

Someone far more well-versed in the Kernel of Windows can stomp in with heavy boots here and correct me, but as far as I know, Ctrl-Alt-Delete is so system, it's "mega system".  The reason is that if programs could latch in to it, you'd end up with a dead desktop the moment some idiot decided it was a great idea to pop up an "Are you sure?" message box when the user realised his computer had gone to hell.

There are guidelines that we should follow as software developers, and trying to change the behaviour of the operating system (however good our intent), will always end in tears.

I suggest you don't try and do this (if it is indeed possible, I've never tried - to be frank), and start thinking about the more important things you can be doing.  If memory serves and the user *does* hit Ctrl-Alt-Delete when you're running a DirectX application, you'll lose the surface/device context (assuming you're full screen).

Exit gracefully, or if you can recover - do so.

Comment: Control-Alt-Del is indeed special, so special that even VMware can't send it directly and can't capture it, although it can hang a notification onto it so that it can tell the hapless user to use Control-Alt-Ins instead.

Comment: I think it`s possible to capture CTRL+ALT+DEL on the kayboard driver level